# How do I set the mtime of a symlink in TCL?

Tags: tcl, symlink, filemtime

`file mtime` can be used to set the modifcation time of a file.  But if it's a symlink, it will set the mtime of the target.  How do I set the mtime of the symlink itself?

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest approach will be to run an [external command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63876/changing-the-timestamp-of-a-symlink):

```
proc SetMtime {filename timestamp} {
    # A little bit of type enforcement; it's not necessary, but avoids potential trouble
    exec touch -h -t [expr {int($timestamp)}] [file normalize $filename]
}
```

This is because Tcl does not provide any native access to the [`utimensat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/utimensat) system call (or its wrapper, [`lutimes(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/lutimes)). You could make your own access functions in a Tcl extension (either directly, or using Critcl or SWIG) but for just setting a single link occasionally, calling out to `touch` with the `-h` option is easiest.

Comment: My reason for looking into this is in part because `-h` is not available in all implementations of `touch`.

Comment: Yeah, but on operating systems where it is absent, it's probably because the underlying OS doesn't support the feature either. At that point, there's not really any sort of workaround.